# How is interest calculated on a debt?

Tags: canada, small-claims-court, debt, british-columbia

For the [notice of payment hearing forum](https://www2.gov.bc.ca/assets/gov/law-crime-and-justice/courthouse-services/court-files-records/court-forms/small-claims/scl013.pdf) it has a section for "payment order" and "interest". How is interest calculated? What percent is it? What time does it start counting from, was it from when the order was made or until the plaintiff receives a copy of the validated order and the objection period was past?

For example if a plaintiff filed the application in January 2020, was awarded in February but didn't receive the validated ordered until March, which date would be used?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs to Money.SE and depends on your contract with your bank.

Comment: @Trish there is no contract, this is a court hearing

Comment: Ask your bank what is the ruling interest?

Comment: What is the nature of the debt and what is underlying dispute about? Ordinarily in the case of a contractual debt, interest is calculated based upon the loan agreement, and in the case of an involuntary debt, like child support, the underlying court order controls, with a statutory rate of interest. There isn't enough context in the question to give a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In British Columbia this is governed by the [Court Order Interest Act](https://www.bclaws.gov.bc.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/00_96079_01)

There are too many whys and wherefores to give a definitive answer as when and on what interest is applicable varies and the rate changes over time and the rate can be agreed (e.g. in a contract) between the parties.